# dynamically adding fieldset with children

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with my jquery code. I have a form with fieldset where are many form fields. After clicking on one div I need to add another fieldset include childrens with same atributes. When I click on div first time, everything looks ok, but on second click, nothing happens. On third click, there are four fieldsets, on fourth click 8 and so forth. I dont know where is a problem

html

```
<form>
  <fieldset class=fieldsett>
    <input>
    <input>
  </fieldset>
<div id="insert">Insert</div>
</form>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
var fieldset_parent = $(".fieldsett").eq(0).clone();
        $("div#insert").click(function(){
           $(".fieldsett").after(fieldset_parent);
        });
});
```

thanks a lot for your help

Comment: once you have `.fieldset` and once `.fieldsett`

Comment: thanks.. it was only mistake here.. in my source code it is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery after method appends the parameterised content after every element in the selector.

So

```
$(".fieldsett").after(fieldset_parent);
```

appends the content after each item exponentially.

Try this instead:

```
$(".fieldsett:last").after(fieldset_parent);
```

See http://api.jquery.com/after/ for information about the after method which has the following description:

*Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements*

Edit: I just noticed that this still has an issue with items disappearing, and I think this has to do with how jquery is appending the cloned element to the DOM. To get around this, i would clone the clone on each append so a unique element is added to the DOM each time.

```
$(function() {    
  var fieldset_parent = $(".fieldsett:eq(0)").clone();
  $("div#insert").click(function(){
    $(".fieldsett:last").after($(fieldset_parent).clone());
  });
});
```

Comment: THANKS a lot boniestlawyer. Its amazing!

Comment: there is one problem.. it doesnt work in IE.. I tested id in IE9 and in Firefox IE tab with same same result.. nothing happens after clicking on button

Comment: I had a look on IE10 (only one available at the moment) and it works correctly as per: http://jsbin.com/ovufuh/3/edit , Is this a new issue?